# code not working error " Expected '{' and instead saw ';'."

Tags: javascript

```
function f() {
    var b = "b";
    return function() {
        alert(b);
        return b;
    };
}
var a = function f();
    alert(a);
​
```

I try to run this code but I have error which I don't understand.

```
Error:
Problem at line 8 character 21: Expected '{' and instead saw ';'.
var a = function f();

Problem at line 8 character 21: Unnecessary semicolon.
var a = function f();

Problem at line 8 character 22: Missing semicolon.
var a = function f();

Implied global: alert 4,9
```

what wrong in this code I want to alert the the privete var from the global scope.
what I should change ?
Many thx.
    ​

Comment: Change `var a = function f();` to `var a = f();`.

Comment: Just some theory: the `function` keyword is used to define a new function. `f` is already defined so it doesn't need `function`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
>  var a = function f();
> ```

That doesn't make any sense.
If you're trying to call the function, just write `f()`.